# Removing `sparse` file attribute

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, ntfs

What's the `sparse` file attribute on NTFS partitions and how can one remove it?

Using Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1.

Comment: Why would you want to remove it?

Comment: @MJZ: I just want to know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nicole Hamilton provided [the description of what sparse files are](https://superuser.com/a/508814/80304).
Let's learn it with an experiment.

### Creating a Sparse File

Start a Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) as Administrator.

1. Creating large file:

   ```
   fsutil file createnew test.nul 1048576
   ```
2. Check its size in Explorer:

   - Size: 1.00 MB (1,048,576 bytes)
   - Size on disk: 1.00 MB (1,048,576 bytes)
3. Let's mark it sparse:

   ```
   fsutil sparse setflag test.nul
   ```
4. Nothing changed so far, the both sizes are still 1.00 MB.
5. Let's mark the entire byte range as sparse:

   ```
   fsutil sparse setrange test.nul 0 1048576
   ```
6. Now the sizes changed dramatically:

   - Size: 1.00 MB (1,048,576 bytes)
   - Size on disk: 1.00 KB (1 024 bytes)
7. You can query if the file is sparse or not with `fsutil`:

   ```
   fsutil sparse queryflag test.nul
   This file is set as sparse
   ```

   Or

   ```
   This file is NOT set as sparse
   ```

The value of *Size on disk* depends on the cluster size of the file system. The default cluster size on NTFS is 4 KB. The drive I used for testing was formatted with 1 KB cluster.

I used this article as [the source](http://habrahabr.ru/post/78018/).

---

### Removing Sparse Attribute

The utility I used in the example does not provide a flag to remove *sparse* attribute.

The simplest way to do is to *copy the file*. The file will lose this special attribute if the application that copies it does not specially preserve the sparse attribute and sparse range.

You can use [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) to clear the sparse attribute. Navigate to the file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to open Attribute dialog. Clear **Sparse** check box. And click **Set** button.
[image: Attributes of test.nul file in Fra Manager]

Comment: NOT WORKING ! ... my file is 30G, I do NOT HAVE space to copy it, and far-manager do nothing when try to set that flag, I press ctrl+a again and attribute is STILL THERE :(

Comment: @THESorcerer I didn't try to use Far Manager to set Sparse attribute, only to clear it. Does your file consists of zeroes only? If you look closely at `fsutil` command line, you'll see that Sparse attribute requires `setrange` to specify the range of bytes "compacted" by sparse attribute. Setting Sparse attribute doesn't automatically analyze the file structure to save disk space, *you* have to handle it.

Comment: The `truncate` utility from `msys2` is able to extend a sparse NTFS file on windows without using disk space. Example:
`touch sparse.vdi ; fsutil sparse setflag sparse.vdi ; truncate --reference original.vdi sparse.vdi ; rsync --archive --inplace --no-whole-file --verbose --progress original.vdi sparse.vdi`

Answer (score 3):

A sparse file is one that has holes in it.  Large sections of binary zeros aren't written to disk.  Here's Microsoft's explanation from [Sparse Files (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> When sparse file functionality is enabled, the system does not
>   allocate hard disk drive space to a file except in regions where it
>   contains nonzero data. When a write operation is attempted where a
>   large amount of the data in the buffer is zeros, the zeros are not
>   written to the file. Instead, the file system creates an internal list
>   containing the locations of the zeros in the file, and this list is
>   consulted during all read operations. When a read operation is
>   performed in areas of the file where zeros were located, the file
>   system returns the appropriate number of zeros in the buffer allocated
>   for the read operation. In this way, maintenance of the sparse file is
>   transparent to all processes that access it, and is more efficient
>   than compression for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 3):

This sparse attrib problem happens all the time with downloaded ISOs for me.

Put this in a batch file and drag-and-drop the target file onto it (with Windows Explorer). Et voilà.

```
fsutil sparse queryflag %1
pause
fsutil sparse setflag %1 0
fsutil sparse queryflag %1
pause
```

This does not work in Windows 7 and 8.x however (possibly Vista too) as `setflag` only accepts *`<filename>`* as a valid parameter and there is no corresponding `clearflag` command. It does however work in Windows 10.