# Can't Mount ISO with File Explorer that Mounts with Other Programs

Tags: windows, windows-8, iso-image

Whenever I try to mount a certain ISO I'm getting the error "Sorry, there was a problem mounting the file" despite the fact that the image mounts perfectly fine using DaemonTools or ImDisk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of (http://superuser.com/questions/508801/removing-sparse-file-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

File Explorer won't mount files that have the sparse flag set:

```
fsutil sparse queryflag PATH_TO_ISO
:: => This file is set as sparse
```

All you need to do is unset the flag:

```
fsutil sparse setflag PATH_TO_ISO 0
fsutil sparse queryflag PATH_TO_ISO
:: => This file is NOT set as sparse
```

If you're too lazy to whip out a command prompt, you can simply duplicate the file to clear the flag.

Comment: [Or use the utility Far Manager](http://superuser.com/questions/508801/removing-sparse-file-attribute)