# Recurring portable drive error: 'The sparse flag in standard information attribute in file _______ is not set.'

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, chkdsk, portable-harddrive

I have a portable drive that often slows Windows 10 boot. When performing an error check on this drive as recommended after booting (Properties->Tools->Error checking), it will say errors were found on the drive. The Event Viewer Chkdsk summary mentions something like:

```
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
The sparse flag in standard information attribute in file 0x1ba91
is not set.
Correcting sparse file record segment 113297.
The sparse flag in standard information attribute in file 0x1bad9
is not set.
Correcting sparse file record segment 113369.[...]

Windows has made corrections to the file system.
No further action is required.
```

The problem is that this error is never fixed but keeps repeating, with a different file identified each time. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this error for good since it slows the boot process?

Comment: Have you tried backing up the data, then formatting the portable drive, then restoring the data? If Windows just does not like the drive due to a "mess" on the drive, then formatting should solve it. If formatting does not solve it, it's likely a hardware issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's a 2TB drive filled mostly with media files and I don't have another with that sort of space available, so it's not something I can try at the moment unfortunately. Any idea what's causing the recurring chkdsk error, though?

Comment: Not really. Try this question/answer, though: http://superuser.com/questions/508801/removing-sparse-file-attribute. Work-around: You could just connect the drive after booting. As for me, I've largely stopped looking into causes of mysterious problems like yours due to time constraints. Won't make me a hero.